# Elasticsearch: get for a substring in the value of a document field?

Tags: elasticsearch

In `mysql` I can use the `sql` `SELECT LEFT(field,4) from table` to search 4 bytes of a field.

`Elasticsearch`  has similar grammar?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With ES, you can use [`script_fields`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html) in order to perform any script computation on existing fields.

In your case, this would translate to making a query like this:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "script_fields" : {
        "left_field" : {
            "script" : {
                "inline": "doc.field.value.substring(0, length)"
                "params": {
                    "length": 4
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your response you'll get a field named `left_field` which will contain the 4 left-most characters of the `field` value.

Also make sure to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) in order for this to work.