# Find length (size) of the array type field in each doc

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a field in my index which is an integer array. I want to add another field which contains the count of the number of elements.

Even an API call that gives the count is fine.

I have found something relevant :
"script" : "doc['MyField'].values.size()"

But I don't know how & where to use it.
Please help!

Comment: What you are looking for is update_by_query, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this using the [Update by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html):

```
POST index/_update_by_query
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }, 
    "script": {
       "source": "ctx._source.arrayLength = ctx._source.MyField.size()"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is about adding a field, how can I just "display" the number of elements in an array field ?

Comment: @secavfr you can leverage `script_fields`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35644126/elasticsearch-get-for-a-substring-in-the-value-of-a-document-field/35645363?

Comment: @secavfr as of 7.11 (to be released any day now), you'll be able to leverage [runtime fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/runtime.html)