# Elasticsearch query to get array size

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have Elasticsearch documents look like:

```
Doc 1:
{
  "name" : "Tom",
  "values" : [
    { "value" : "value 1" },
    { "value" : "value 2" },
    { "value" : "value 3" }
  ]
}

Doc 2:
{
  "name" : "Bob",
  "values" : [
    { "value" : "value 1" },
    { "value" : "value 2" }
  ]
}
```

How can I query by docs which the `values` array size is larger than 2?

Comment: A better approach would be this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53113822/find-length-size-of-the-array-type-field-in-each-doc/53113928#53113928 (hint: have another field containing the size of the array)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this to your bool query.

```
"filter" : {
    "script" : {
        "script" : "doc['values'].values.size() > 2"
    }
}
```

`filter` filters the document which matches the condition.

`size()` returns the size of the array.

`doc['values']` looks for `values` field.